# Installation of HP Laserjet P1007 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hp

The O/S of Desktop in question was UBUNTU 14.04. Few days back this was formatted and UBUNTU 16.04 was installed. However after upgrading when it was found that the printer is not working, I downloaded HPLIP from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-i...nting/gethplip. Notwithstanding, the position is same. How to resolve the issue?

The issue could be resolved yesterday with the procedure described in the link. https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-hp-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktop/

Therefore, now it stands **SOLVED**.

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: then try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/800289/hp-printer-install-fail and edit your question to include the steps you have taken rather than taking up space adding comments.